# Can't catch an exception, system just closes

Tags: python, api, exception, python-requests, timeout

I've implemented an orchestrator in python that makes some requisitions to an API. My problem is that sometimes it gets stucked in a request. To solve that I used the timeout parameter. Now I want to implement something so I can retry doing the requisition, but first I need to take care of the exception. For that I tried this:

```
    uri = MS_MONITOR + "/api/monitor/advise/lawsuit/total/withProgressDaily"
    try:
        response = requests.get(uri, headers={"Correlation-Id": CORRELATION_ID}, timeout = 10)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        logging.info("[{}] [{}] {}".format("ERROR de Timeout", response.status_code, uri))
        print("Deu timeout")
```

I put the timeout as 10 just to force it to happen, the problem is that it doesn't go into the exception part below, the cmd just closes. I've tried using this one too but it didn't work either:

```
except requests.exceptions.Timeout
```

If there's lack of information in my post please let me know so I'll provide it. Thank you!

Comment: Which type of `Exception` is being `raise`d by `requests`? If the code raises an exception but doesn't enter the `except` clause, it's because you're not catching the exception that's being raised or some code within the `try` is handling the exception.

Comment: It should be raising a Timeout exception because I'm forcing it to time out. The problem is that I can't see any message because as soon as the time out time passes, the cmd closes. It seems like after it the time out happens, it's executing a sys.exit but there isn't a sys.exit in the code.

Comment: Try catching `Exception` rather than `requests.exceptions.Timeout` and use `print` to write any info you can get about the exception to `stdout`, this may help you figure out what's going on. Timeouts in the real world are difficult to debug because they're typically intermittent. It's possible that sometimes this code raises a different exception type.

Comment: Hey I just discovered what happened. It was closing because I declared my response inside the try and after that I tried using it out of it. I think I can make it work now. Thanks. It was helpful to help me solving the suddenly closing problem and now it's going to help me with the main problem. Thank you!

Comment: Great. Next time, please post all of the relevant code to avoid red-herrings like this.